# "Attempting to Reference a deleted function" error when attempting to initialize static RenderWindor

Tags: c++, sfml

Error:

[image]

...is on line 15, where I try to initialize window:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

static class Renderer {

public:
    static sf::RenderWindow window;
    
      
};
sf::RenderWindow Renderer::window = sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(1200, 1000), "Proj");
class Quad {
public:
    sf::Vector2<float> Scale;
    sf::Vector2<float> Pos;
public:
    Quad(sf::Vector2<float> P, sf::Vector2<float> S) {
        Pos = P;
        Scale = S;
    }
    sf::RectangleShape RenderMe() {
        sf::RectangleShape s;
        s.setScale(Scale);
        s.setPosition(Pos);
        return s;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    
        new Renderer;

       
       
           Quad s(sf::Vector2<float>(40,40), sf::Vector2<float>(20,20));
           


        while (Renderer::window.isOpen())
        {
            sf::Event event;
            while (Renderer::window.pollEvent(event))
            {
                if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                    Renderer::window.close();
            }

            Renderer::window.clear();
            Renderer::window.draw(s.RenderMe());
            Renderer::window.display();
        }

        return 0;
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Everything else in the script works.

As far as I can tell, I have set up my filesystems correctly, and all issues are with my script (I think)

I have mostly tried moving around the init, as well as changing certain bits, like not including all of it, but those all caused different errors and this seemed the most correct.

Comment: You have written a ton of code for a poor implementation of a global variable. Please read a C++ book.

Comment: That's interesting, however, I am fine with having bad code as long as it works. Do you know why the init is saying there is a deleted func? And if so how could I fix it? you really aren't being helpful

Comment: The error is literally saying "you cannot use a copy constructor for this class".

Comment: Other stuff: `new Renderer` by itself is syntactically correct but utterly useless. Brute forcing your way through the syntax is not the way to go, I'm afraid.

Comment: "I am fine with having bad code as long as it works" - then you are never going to improve. Just avoid using globals. Why do you not just use this in your main:      `sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove everything to do with class `Renderer` and `Renderer::window`.
Put a single definition at the top of your main function:

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1200, 1000), "Proj");
```

and use `window` wherever you used `Renderer::window`.

If you insist on having a Renderer object, it should look like this:

```
class Renderer {
  public:
    sf::RenderWindow window;
    Renderer() : window(sf::VideoMode(1200, 1000), "Proj")) {}
};
```

and a simple `Renderer r;` in your main function will suffice.

Comment: alright, I thought a global would be better here, but i'll just use a not-global. it should still work, but thanks for answering the question and helping me improve.

Comment: The rule of thumb: [Never use globals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-in-use-of-global-variables). There are even [jokes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426321/global-variables-joke) about people using global variables.

Comment: See edit for what Renderer should have looked like

Comment: Changing from copy-initialization to direct-initialization would also have solved the problem for the static member variable.